# Ternary inside of map returning no results

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a very basic filter system. I currently have the whole object displaying as a list which is great however when I try to copy the same component with a ternary statement inside of the map function it returns no results, it compiles with no errors but just does not display any items within the object.

I'm fairly new to this so please explain like I'm 5.

The filtered component:

```
function Torquay() {
  return (

    <div className="container">

      <div className="row">

        {spaces.map(item => {
          return item.town === 'Torquay' ?
            <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">

              <div className="card mb-sm-5">
                  <span className="badge badge-light">{item.town}</span>
                  <h4 className="card-title">{item.name}</h4>

                  <div className="wifi">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-wifi"><path d="M5 12.55a11 11 0 0 1 14.08 0"></path><path d="M1.42 9a16 16 0 0 1 21.16 0"></path><path d="M8.53 16.11a6 6 0 0 1 6.95 0"></path><line x1="12" y1="20" x2="12.01" y2="20"></line></svg>
                    <h6>{item.net}Mbps</h6>
                  </div>

                  <div className="amenities">
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        {item.day === true ? <span role="img" aria-label="Open in day"></span> : null}
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        {item.night === true ? <span role="img" aria-label="Open at night"></span> : null}
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        {item.dog === true ? <span role="img" aria-label="Dog friendly"></span> : null}
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        {item.parking === true ? <span role="img" aria-label="Car parking"></span> : null}
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>

                  <img src={item.image} className="card-img-top" alt="..."/>
              </div>

            </div>
          : null}

        )}

      </div>

    </div>
  );
}
```

The object structure:

```
const spaces = [
  {
    name: 'WeSup Torquay',
    image: '/img/wesup/1.jpg',
    town: 'Torquay',
    net: 20,
    parking: true,
    dog: true,
    day: true,
    night: true,
  },
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That seems okay to me as a first look. Where do you define `spaces`? Is there any error on the console?

Comment: First, wrap the whole <div className="col-sm..."> in parentheses like (<div>...</div>). Second, you don't need a map for the filtering, you need a filter method for this purpose. You can find more details here https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: The code you shared should technically work as long as `spaces` contains that element. See this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-robinson-1oi14). Can you verify the value of `spaces`?

Comment: @norbitrial There are no relevant errors in the console. I import spaces, works fine on the full list just not with the ternary op.

Answer (score 1):

You have your return condition before the Ternary Op. Or do it after Like

```
function Torquay() {
  return (

    <div className="container">

      <div className="row">

        {spaces.map(item => {
          return item.town === 'Torquay' && <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
              <div className="card mb-sm-5">
                  <span className="badge badge-light">{item.town}</span>
                  <h4 className="card-title">{item.name}</h4>

                  <div className="wifi">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-wifi"><path d="M5 12.55a11 11 0 0 1 14.08 0"></path><path d="M1.42 9a16 16 0 0 1 21.16 0"></path><path d="M8.53 16.11a6 6 0 0 1 6.95 0"></path><line x1="12" y1="20" x2="12.01" y2="20"></line></svg>
                    <h6>{item.net}Mbps</h6>
                  </div>

                  <div className="amenities">
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        {item.day === true ? <span role="img" aria-label="Open in day"></span> : null}
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        {item.night === true ? <span role="img" aria-label="Open at night"></span> : null}
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        {item.dog === true ? <span role="img" aria-label="Dog friendly"></span> : null}
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        {item.parking === true ? <span role="img" aria-label="Car parking"></span> : null}
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>

                  <img src={item.image} className="card-img-top" alt="..."/>
              </div>

            </div>
          }
        )}

      </div>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve my issue, again no compile errors, it's just showing no results. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've now fixed this issue, it was due to not defining the path of the component when utilising react router. Thanks all for letting me know that it technically should work (although not the best approach).